# Keras (TF backend) segmentation fault on creating LSTM

Tags: linux, tensorflow, keras, bidirectional

I'm trying standard deep learning models on my MacBook Pro and iMac computers before putting them on a Linux GPU server to run. I work on all these systems within a py27 conda environment. Using latest versions of Keras and Tensorflow on all systems (but different distributions because the server is a linux machine and also has tensor flow-gpu version). When I run a simple CNN, on all platforms it works well from building to training. However, trying an RNN, I get Segmentation Fault on the linux server at the model building point where I add an Bidirectional (LSTM or GRU) layer. The same codes run perfectly on my two Mac systems. I'm confused because the CNN runs well on the GPU of the Linux server, is there a bug in tensorflow-gpu linux distribution related to the recurrent layers?

- Linux Server (Ubuntu 16.04.3): tensorflow-gpu 1.3.0 and Keras 2.1.2
- Mac systems (two different OS): tensorflow 1.1.0 and Keras 2.1.2

```html
def prepare_rnn_model_1(word_index, embedding_matrix):
    print("*** 1")
    embedding_layer = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                                EMBEDDING_DIM,
                                weights=[embedding_matrix],
                                input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                                trainable=True)

    print("*** 2")
    sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
    print("*** 3")
    embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)
    print("*** 4")
    l_lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(100))(embedded_sequences)
    print("*** 5")
    preds = Dense(CLASSES, activation='softmax')(l_lstm)
    print("*** 6")
    model = Model(sequence_input, preds)
    print("*** 7")
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='rmsprop',
                  metrics=['acc'])
    return model
```

Comment: can you give example code?

Comment: It's a long code that works for the CNN, so I just copied the part specific to RNN. The segfault occurs right when the LSTM layer is added (after print 4).

Comment: For me it was some version incompatibility. The latest `tensorflow-gpu` installation from `conda` in a fresh environment gives me this error, while an older installation works fine (non-RNN layers worked fine on the latest version). Since `conda` also installs CUDA, cuDNN and many other non-python and python dependencies for `tensorflow-gpu`, it is hard to pinpoint the faulty dependency.